# Copying a cell with partial formatting of text

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell in Google Sheets with formatted text content. Something like this:

> You must complete **both** parts of the assignment.

If I copy that cell into another cell, the bold formatting is lost. Is there a way to copy both the content and the formatting?

Comment: When I select a cell with such formatting, press Ctrl-C, and then press Ctrl-V on another cell, the formatting is preserved. How are you copying it?

Comment: I'm doing, basically, exactly the same thing. Selecting the text in the cell and then typing Command-C (copy on a Mac) followed by Command-V (paste) in the new cell. I think I've had this happen in both Chrome and Safari.

Comment: When you say "in the new cell", is it within the spreadsheet grid or in the "fx" window on top?

Comment: Within the grid.

Comment: @Norma: Ok, this is very weird. Your first comment made me think about how I was selecting the text. I usually would either drag to select or type Command-A (select all) in the cell. It sounded like you might be just clicking in the cell. So I tried that. It works! *But,* if I use my method it does not work. ***But,*** if I use your method (just click in the cell then type Command-C), and later use my method, **then** my method also works. This is in Safari on Yosemite (OS X 10.11, the latest version at the moment).

Answer (score 3):

Partial formatting of cell text is a recent addition to Google Sheets, and it is still pretty fragile. The following works:

1. Select a cell
2. Press Ctrl-C (or Command-C)
3. Select another cell
4. Press Ctrl-V (or Command-V)

Other methods, described below, are not as successful.

If one double-clicks a cell, selects **all** of its content, and copy-pastes that, the partial formatting may or may not be preserved (depending on the previous state of clipboard).

If one double-clicks a cell, selects **some** of its content, and copy-pastes that, the partial formatting is not preserved.